# Check if date is within X number of days of today

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, math

I have a date variable being set on my page like this:

```
startDate =  "03/28/2017";
```

How can I check if that date is 7 or less days before **today's** date?

It will need to be used in a conditional if statement.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a code writing service. Have a look at momentjs if you haven't already

Comment: You shouls use moment.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get difference between 2 dates in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: @DarrenSweeney  added what I have tried

Comment: @all this is a bit different than 'get difference between 2 dates' as I am not able to set todays date - it needs to be set automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `moment.js`,

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b) // 86400000
```

or even better, it has an inbuilt method, which says after how many days.

```
moment([2007, 0, 29]).toNow(); // in 4 years
```

and if you want to use old plain javascript :

```
var date1 = new Date("3/30/2017");
var date2 = new Date("3/23/2017");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

If you want to compare with `today`

```
var date1 = new Date("3/23/2017")
var date2 = new Date();
```

Comment: Thank you @Dave  -  this would work except I would need date1 to populate dynamically though.  Any ideas how date1 can dynamically set to today's date?

Comment: So, you want your date1 to be current date or something you'll get from server?

Comment: Yes, the current date!

Comment: Please don't suggest parsing strings with a bulit-in parser (Date constructor and Date.parse), it should be done manually or with a library, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)